# Excluding rows or columns from Checkbox macro

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, range

So, I have based a lot of functions on a sheet on checkboxes.
It grew beyond the original scope, and now I needed to add a few more control textboxes
The problem is, I wrote a script which would Unmark blank checkboxes if a cell in the row was blank (the cell in G column), and now that I have a few more checkboxes to control other functions, my script unfortunately affects the others.
Here is the script:

```
Sub UnMarkBlankCheckBoxes()

Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes
    If ws.Range("G" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
        chk.Value = False
    Else
        chk.Value = True
    End If
Next chk

End Sub
```

I need to be able to either select within a specific range (only column E), OR Exclude everything else. I have been trying things, but cant get it to work.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `If chk.TopLeftCell.Column = 5 Then` will check if the checkbox is in column 5 which is column E. This way you can limit it to column E.

Comment: Awesome. That worked great! And if I have multiple columns? (c,d,e)

Comment: Okay, so the easiest way, but probably not the most elegant, was to copy the entire if statement nested in the For Each chk statement and make the .column = 3, and then 4 and then 5. It works, but if there is a better way/cleaner code I would love to know it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple columns use `>=` and `<=` in connection with `And`

```
For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes
    If chk.TopLeftCell.Column >= 3 And chk.TopLeftCell.Column <= 5 Then
        If ws.Range("G" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
           chk.Value = False
        Else
            chk.Value = True
        End If
    End If
Next chk
```

Or something like

```
If chk.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 Or chk.TopLeftCell.Column = 4 Or chk.TopLeftCell.Column = 6 Then
```

Comment: Awesome. Monday morning for me, must be slow today :D I didn't even think about greater than less than statements or or! Thanks a lot!